# another textarea input related query

Tags: css, textarea, line-breaks

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with my CSS.. any help would be appreciated..

the CSS

```
#commentbox {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFF0;
  display: block;
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

#commentbox .commenter_name {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #660000;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#commentbox .comment_content {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

This is my Form Textarea

```
<textarea name="vt_comment" cols="50" rows="5" wrap="hard" class="nontextarea" ></textarea>
```

This is the code that displays the Comment

```
<?php if ($totalRows_cmnts_disp>0) { // Show only if there are Comments
        do { ?>
<div id="commentbox">
  <!--Show Commenter Name -->
  <div class="commenter_name">
    <?php if ($row_cmnts_disp['member_nick']>"") {
            echo $row_cmnts_disp['member_nick'] ; 
            } else {
            echo $row_cmnts_disp['member_fname'] . ' ' . $row_list_solo['member_sname'] ; 
            } ?> commented
  </div>

  <!--Show Comment -->
  <div class="comment_content">
    <?php echo $row_cmnts_disp['vt_comment']; ?>
  </div>

</div>
<?php } while ($row_cmnts_disp = mysql_fetch_assoc($cmnts_disp)); 
    } // Show only if there are Comments loop ends 
    ?>
```

This is how it gets stored in the DB

```
1st Line of the Comment

2nd Line of the Comment with just a Line break

Double Line Break
```

and this is how it is displayed on the site (with spaces in the front of the 1st line)

```
Swami Donanandha commented

            hello

hello
hello

hello
```

[as displayed online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJqEQ.jpg)

---

whatever changes I try,  I'm not able to remove the spaces before the 1st line of the comment, unless I remove the white-space:pre-wrap setting in the CSS...and if i do that the line breaks vanish displaying just one long sentence....

```
Swami Donanandha commented
1st Line of the Comment 2nd Line of the Comment with just a Line break           Double Line Break
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the **white-space: pre-wrap** attribute and echo'ing a HTML break tag at the end of each comment?

```
<?php if ($totalRows_cmnts_disp>0) { // Show only if there are Comments
    do { ?>
    <div id="commentbox"> 
        <!--Show Commenter Name --> 
        <div class="commenter_name"><?php if ($row_cmnts_disp['member_nick']>"") {
        echo $row_cmnts_disp['member_nick'] ; 
        } else {
        echo $row_cmnts_disp['member_fname'] . ' ' . $row_list_solo['member_sname'] ; 
        } ?>
        commented
        </div>

        <!--Show Comment: Added Break Tag Below-->
        <div class="comment_content">
        <?php echo "<p class='comment'>" + $row_cmnts_disp['vt_comment'] + "</p><br>"; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php } while ($row_cmnts_disp = mysql_fetch_assoc($cmnts_disp)); 
   } // Show only if there are Comments loop ends 
?>
```

The reason your comments concatenate into one long string after removing the white-space attribute is because of the **float: left** attribute in the .comment_content class. Updating the class to the following should fix the long string problem you have;

```
#commentbox .comment_content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the **float: left** attribute from the CSS as well?

Comment: the html <br> break at the end of each comment looks ambiguous as every comment is displaying separately 

the + symbol takes it as a calculation and returns a number....

if i remove the  clear:both; attribute, the Commenters name and the Comment are displayed on the same line...

Comment: Is a single 'vt_comment' a string? Does it have any HTML attributes in said string? Wrapping the comment in a HTML tag should prevent it from treating it as a calculation.

Comment: Tom, the vt_comment is text... comments made on a post through a textarea, which is a TinyMCE with a nontextarea class.. I have posted it in my query

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out... by adding the nl2br clause before the DB insert

```
$vt_comment = nl2br($_POST['vt_comment']);
```

and removing the white-space:pre-wrap from the CSS

Though I still don't have a clue why the extra spaces were getting added earlier :-)